Inserting "background" material after the previous line
This is sort of a code review question.
I wrote a macro \backbelow to insert "background" material after the previous line. This can be used to wrap the text around a figure without wrapfig package. Here is an example of possible usage:
\newsavebox{\Figure}
%% Figure source: https://www.ctan.org/lion/files/ctanlion.eps
\sbox{\Figure}{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{ctanlion.eps}}

\newlength{\FigureWidth}
\setlength{\FigureWidth}{\wd\Figure}

\newlength{\FigureSkip}
\setlength{\FigureSkip}{\FigureWidth}
\addtolength{\FigureSkip}{\columnsep}

This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long
long sentence.

\backbelow{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\usebox{\Figure}}}
\setlength{\rightskip}{\FigureSkip}

Consider an equation:
\[
  \addtolength{\displaywidth}{-\FigureSkip}
  x^2 = 1.
\]
This was not a long long long long long long long long long long equation.

Consider a few items:
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\FigureSkip}
  \item
    first long long long long long long long long long long long long item.
  \item
    second long long long long long long long long long long long long item.
  \item
    \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}
    third long long long long long long long long long long long long long
    long long item.
\end{enumerate}

Output:

Here is my definition of \backbelow:
\newcommand{\backbelow}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \count255=\prevgraf
  \dimen255=\prevdepth
  \skip255=\lastskip
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \nointerlineskip
  \hbox{%
    \vtop to 0pt{%
      \vskip\skip255
      \prevdepth=\dimen255
      \prevgraf=\count255
      \box0\vss
    }%
  }%
  \vskip\skip255
  \prevdepth=\dimen255
  \prevgraf=\count255
}

Here \sbox is used instead of \setbox because it is supposed to be more "robust," see this answer. A part of this code is based on this answer to my previous question.
My question: is there any problem with my definition of \backbelow? Can anything be improved?
Here is the code that I used to test that my implementation is working as intended:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\backbelow}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \count255=\prevgraf
  \dimen255=\prevdepth
  \skip255=\lastskip
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \nointerlineskip
  \hbox{%
    \vtop to 0pt{%
      \vskip\skip255
      \prevdepth=\dimen255
      \prevgraf=\count255
      \box0\vss
    }%
  }%
  \vskip\skip255
  \prevdepth=\dimen255
  \prevgraf=\count255
}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\XX}{\texttt{XX}}
\newcommand{\YYY}{\texttt{YYY}}
\newcommand{\ZZZ}{\texttt{ZZZ}}

\newcommand{\someHStuff}{%
  \hspace{1.5cm}\vtop{\hsize=1cm\noindent\YYY\\\ZZZ}%
}

\newcommand{\testcase}{%
  \section*{Between paragraphs:}

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash hbox\{...\}}:

  \hbox{\someHStuff}

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}nothing:

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash backbelow\{...\}}:

  \backbelow{\someHStuff}

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash kern 0pt}:

  \kern 0pt

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash null}:

  \null

  \noindent
  \texttt{XXXXXX}

  \section*{Inside a paragraph:}

  \noindent
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash hbox\{...\}}:
  \vadjust{\hbox{\someHStuff}}\\
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}nothing:\\
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash backbelow\{...\}}:
  \vadjust{\backbelow{\someHStuff}}\\
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash kern 0pt}:
  \vadjust{\kern 0pt}\\
  \XX\XX\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash null}:
  \vadjust{\null}\\
  \XX\XX\XX

  \section*{Between lists:}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash hbox\{...\}}:
  \end{itemize}

  \hbox{\someHStuff}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX\hspace{1.5cm}nothing:
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash backbelow\{...\}}:
  \end{itemize}

  \backbelow{\someHStuff}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash kern 0pt}:
  \end{itemize}

  \kern 0pt

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX\hspace{1.5cm}\texttt{\textbackslash null}:
  \end{itemize}

  \null

  \begin{itemize}
    \item\XX
  \end{itemize}

  \hrule width\linewidth
}

\twocolumn
\testcase
\newpage
\renewcommand{\backbelow}[1]{}
\testcase

\end{document}

Output:


Some quick observations: \backbelow should be defined as protected, \<register>255 are not safe to use as scratch variables, not all the box commands you've used are colour-safe (but it's probably fine here), and you probably want to add some penalties to make sure that the figure can't be separated from it's surrounding paragraphs. I'll try and write a full answer later when I have access to a computer. Also, I'm assuming that you're already familiar with \hangindent and \parshape?

@MaxChernoff, thanks for the comment. Yes, I've used \hangindent before and I know about \parshape.
